# Blender on IBM Cloud (Cloud Foundry)

Tags: django, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, blender

I'm currently developing a web application (Django 2.0) application.
My app will be deployed on IBM Cloud (Cloud Foundry) using python build-pack.
One of my requirements is to install [blender](https://www.blender.org/).

Everything else is very well, but for blender installation.
What I've tried so far was:

- I tried access my app using SSH connection, but surely I don't have root access to `apt-get install blender`!!
- And tried to include blender in `packages.json` file and push that file using `cf push my-app`.
  But nothing worked for me.

In another shorter question: what is the main approach in Cloud Foundry Apps to install packages like when we use `apt-get install` in Ubuntu / Debian.

Please correct me if I did anything wrong, or guide me with headlines to solve this problem!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple options for you to install packages if they cannot be installed using the regular **requirements** file (which is the preferred way):

- Download the relevant libraries and put them in subfolders of the app before pushing it. The libraries will be uploaded. That is how I would do it.
- Once you have an SSH connection, use secure copy (scp) to upload the files and place them in the subfolders where they are expected.

Regarding Blender, the question is what you need in addition to having the code copied over. Does it need a running daemon? Are there more dependencies? You would need to share more information about your specific app to answer that. Maybe, packaging everything as one or more containers and run it on Kubernetes or a combination of Cloud Foundry and Kubernetes is a better way.

Comment: Thank you @data_henrik for your solution, in fact it didn't completely solved my problem but it's quite an interesting approach to keep in mind.
I'll try to keep working in that approach as it seems to be the most effective for now!!
Thanks for your help and I'll mark your answer Accepted.